# how can I Display image in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, image, exoplayer

I have list of URLs mix with videos and images. I want to display both using ExoPlayer. I could display videos in the ExoPlayer, however when I try to display image I am getting a black screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As per the Exo player developer console, it's mentioned that Exo player only used for the Audio and Video.

Comment: Add ImageView and Exoplayer in Framelayout. Show Image (That is knows as thumbnails) in imageView and on tap of ImageView Hide it and show ExoPlayer and play it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use exoplayer-ui:r2.5.4 and SimpleExoPlayerView has built in image view.
you can set your image with **default_artwork**  attribute in xml, for example:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:default_artwork="@drawable/default_media_artwork"
    app:use_artwork="true"/>
```

Hope to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm trying to use the `ImageView` as a thumbnail out of `exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView`, it's not working as I expected. For example, the thumbnail itself should be placed above the video surface but under the playback controls.

At the same time, all with `artwork` is just about the audio source. Therefore, the drawable assigned to `app:default_artwork` does not work for video media source although I set `app:use_artwork` to `true`.

Here is the **working solution** for me.

ExoPlayer library comes with possibility for customizing the [player view layout](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_simple_player_view.xml) and [playback control layout](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml).

You have got two options to implement thumbnail in the playerview.

1. Create custom layout file named `exo_simple_player_view.xml`. You can copy the layout content from library. And then add the `ImageView` within the `AspectRatioFrameLayout` of `@id/exo_content_frame` or anywhere else in the layout. Please be careful that your imageview is not covered by any other elements in the layout.
2. Create custom layout file with custom name. And then link that layout to the `PlayerView` using `app:player_layout_id`.

The #1 is for the case that you want to have custom layout for all player views in your app while #2 is just for the case for the single player view on specific page.

Once you created the layout file and linked, you can simply find your image view with the ID and set any drawable, or image url using Glide or so on.

Comment: i wanted to set custom image stored in firebase storage using Glide while playing audio files. The #1 part was the answer i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! but my thumbnail is not hiding after the video is playing! its like image above video ! does i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:default_artwork="@drawable/default_media_artwork"
        app:use_artwork="true"
        app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        app:show_buffering="when_playing" />
```